# Parent creating child object

Tags: vb.net, parent-child

I'm writing an application that has Reactor and Zone objects. Each Reactor has a variable number of zones, and stores them in a private field called _zones.

In turn, each Zone must know to which Reactor does it belong, so it stores a pointer to its reactor in a private field. I assign this field by passing a reactor object into the Zone constructor.

Here is the sample code:

```
Public Class Reactor
    Private _zones As New List(Of Zone)
End Class

Public Class Zone
    Private _reactor As Reactor

    Public Sub New(ByVal reactor As Reactor)
        _reactor = reactor
    End Sub
End Class
```

My question is: since each Zone needs to have a reactor passed to its constructor, which of this two approaches do you consider to be better:

1. Create Zones only with a method in Reactor.

   ```
   Public Class Reactor
       Private _zones As New List(Of Zone)

       Public Sub CreateZone()
           _zones.Add(New Zone(Me))
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
2. Create zones and them add them to the reactor

   ```
   Public Class Reactor
       Private _zones As New List(Of Zone)

       Public Sub AddZone(ByVal z As Zone)
           _zones.Add(z)
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```

I suppose that the chosen option depends on the concrete case, but I would like to know if one of these options is considered generally as a best practice. Also, any experience about similar cases would be very useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the first option is preferred.  The problem with the second approach is that it would be possible to create a `Zone`, giving it `reactorA` in its constructor, but then add it to `reactorB`.  Or, you could add the same `Zone` to two different `Reactor` objects.  You could of course add error-checking for that and throw an exception in the case of a mismatch, but as long as the design requires the parent/child relationship, you'll never be likely to be in a position where you need to create a `Zone`, but you don't have access to its `Reactor`.  As long as you're likely to always have access to the `Reactor` when you need to create the `Zone`, then there's no reason not to encapsulate it all by putting the "create" method in the `Reactor` class.

For instance, I have created a grid object, which defines a grid table to be printed to a page or to the screen.  It contains a list of rows and the rows each contain a list of cells.  The rows need a reference back to their grid and the cells need a reference back to their row.  So, I simply implemented it in a way where you tell the grid that you want to add a row and give it the size, like this:

```
myGrid.Rows.Add(100)
```

And the `Add` method returns the Row object, so you can get it easily like this:

```
Dim row As GridRow = myGrid.Rows.Add(100)
row.PenWidthTop = 1
```

This design works very well for that particular situation.  Since it's very unlikely that I'll ever need to create a row in a place where I won't already have a reference to the parent grid, it makes it nice and easy to work with.

If you ever do run into a situation where you need to be able to create `Zone` objects independently, and then add them to the `Reactor` later, you could always add that as a secondary option.  There's nothing about the first method which precludes you from adding the second method at a later time.  For instance, you could make it so that `Zone` objects allow themselves to be creates without a parent `Reactor`, and then, when they are added to the `Reactor`, the `Reactor` can set a property on the `Zone` to tell it who it's parent `Reactor` is.  You could have the `ParentReactor` property on the `Zone` class throw an exception if you try to change it after it's been already set before, like this:

```
Public Class Zone
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(parentReactor As Reactor)
        _parentReactor = parentReactor
    End Sub

    Private _parentReactor As Reactor

    Public Property ParentReactor As Reactor
        Get
            Return _parentReactor
        End Get
        Set(value As Reactor)
            If _parentReactor IsNot Nothing Then
                Throw New Exception("This zone has already been added to a Reactor")
            End If
            _parentReactor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' ...
End Class
```

Comment: You covered every aspect I was thinking about, also how to obtain a Zone with and without an assigned parent reactor, for testing purposes. Thanks!